# Fresh gitorious install – push fails with EOFError

Tags: ruby, git, gitorious, eoferror

I'm deploying Gitorious on an Ubuntu 11.04 machine. 
Everything works, except pushing.

The client gets this:

```
$ git push origin master 

== Gitorious: 
========================================================== 
fatal error 
======================================================================== 

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

And the server shows this in *gitorious_auth.log*:

```
I, [2012-05-08 18:40:45#7589]  INFO -- : Connection from "12.34.56.78 
50393 22" (admin): git-receive-pack 'test/test.git' 
F, [2012-05-08 18:40:45#7589] FATAL -- : EOFError end of file 
reached: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `sysread' 
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill' 
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout' 
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout' 
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill' 
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil' 
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline' 
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2028:in `read_status_line' 
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2017:in `read_new' 
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1051:in `request' 
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:772:in `get' 
  /var/www/gitorious/script/../lib/gitorious/ssh/client.rb:85:in 
`configuration' 
  /var/www/gitorious/script/../lib/gitorious/ssh/client.rb:59:in 
`real_path' 
  /var/www/gitorious/script/../lib/gitorious/ssh/client.rb:73:in 
`to_git_shell_argument' 
  /usr/bin/gitorious:60
```

How can I make pushing work?

Best,

Ruben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem was caused by a faulty `gitorious_client_host` setting, which I had naively set to `localhost`.

What happened then in `/lib/gitorious/ssh/client.rb:85` was that gitorious tried to fetch the repositories configuration through `http://localhost/project/repo`, but the nginx server had not been configured to serve the gitorious application from `localhost`.

Two possible **solutions**:

1. Set the `gitorious_client_host` setting to your public gitorious hostname.
2. Change your nginx or other server configuration to also serve gitorious from `localhost`.

However, the second solution could cause trouble with other applications.